# How to solve attribute error: 'Cursor' object has no attribute 'noCursorTimeout' in pymongo?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pymongo, pymongo-3.x

I'm trying to set noCursorTimeout in the session following this instruction from MongoDB docs.
But I'm getting the error: `AttributeError: 'Cursor' object has no attribute 'noCursorTimeout'`

I can't wonder why I'm getting this.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient as Connection
from datetime import datetime

conn = Connection(get_uri())
with conn as conn:
  collection = conn['db_name']['my_collection']
  documents_cursor = collection.find(query).noCursorTimeout() # same with .maxTimeMS()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the document, you should use it like this:

```js
cursor = collection.find({"a": 1}, no_cursor_timeout=True)
```

Reference: https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/migrate-to-pymongo3.html#timeout-replaced-by-no-cursor-timeout

Comment: Link is broken..

Answer (score 0):

please refer: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.4/reference/method/cursor.noCursorTimeout/#session-idle-timeout-overrides-nocursortimeout

it provide a js example, I write a python example:

```
import pymongo
from datetime import datetime
myclient = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://xxx:xxx@ip:port/")

with myclient.start_session() as session:
    mydb = myclient["db"]
    mycol = mydb["collection"]
    a = datetime.now()
    for item in mycol.find(no_cursor_timeout=True, session=session):
        print(item)
        # deal with your data
        b = datetime.now()
        if (b - a).seconds > 1799:
            a = datetime.now()
            mycol.admin.command(
                'refreshSessions', [session.session_id], session=session)
```

Please change as your own.